# is 'user_id' a keyword in $_SESSION['user_id']?

Tags: php, session

I have studied the following code:

```
$this->user_id = $_SESSION['user_id']=$user->id;
```

but `$_SESSION['user_id']`  this does not make any sense to me. 'user_id' inside $_SESSION[] is not any name attribute or input field name. So is user_id is a keyword reserved in php? if so what is the significance of this keyword?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$_SESSION` are super global variables which **store values in SESSION and can be accessed like arrays**. So `user_id` is just an index of a value in Session *not a reserved keyword*.

On the following statement

`$this->user_id = $_SESSION['user_id']=$user->id`;

Value from `$user -> id` is stored in two places (1) `$this -> user_id` and (2) `$_SESSION['user_id']`

Just like `user_id` a session can hold any random indices. For example

```
$_SESSION['asdfsafasfsadfasd'] = 'aasfsafasfasfasfasf';
```

Comment: that means here 'user_id' is as like as a variable to store information. Is it?

Comment: @sattar_kuet.bd, It is exactly like a variable.

Answer (score 2):

This line of code sets `$this->user_id` and the session variable `user_id` to the value of `$user->id`. It's as simple as that. `$_SESSION['user_id']` is not a reserved key.

It may mean something in the particular bit of code you're working with. In this case, it looks like it might be part of a login process - setting a session variable with the user's ID so they're seen as authenticated in subsequent pageviews.